# Difference b/w llvm-ld and llvm-link

Tags: c, linux, llvm, clang, x86-64

What is the difference between **llvm-ld** and **llvm-link**? I suppose **llvm-ld** performs link time optimization while **llvm-link** doesn't. Am I right?

Answer (score 8):

`llvm-ld` is a drop-in replacement for the system linker that supports both LLVM bitcode and native code. It produces bitcode executables by default (ie the resulting executable invokes the bitcode interpreter), but can also be used to produced native executables.

I don't use `llvm-ld` directly as it's more convenient to use the `llvmc` and `clang` frontends, which invoke the appropriate programs of the LLVM toolchain as necessary (*note:* `llvmc` was marked experimental and appears to have been removed in the 3.0 release).

`llvm-link` is a more low-level tool which joins several bitcode files into a single one. The documentation doesn't mention if it does optimizations, but it [doesn't appear to do so](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Linker/LinkModules.cpp?view=markup&sortby=rev). The next optimization passes will be triggered on native code generation.

Comment: also llvm-ld will be removed in 3.1